# AWS CloudShell command that will allow to test login in order to verify if I set the password correctly for a User Account in a AWS Cognito Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I have a AWS AMS Console account.

I've deployed an AWS Cognito Service. The aforementioned AWS Cognito Service has a User pool which in turn contains an App Client.

There is a User account setup in the aforementioned AWS Cognito Service

I can setup the password for the aforementioned User account via the following command within AWS CloudShell:

> aws cognito-idp admin-set-user-password --user-pool-id value
> --username value --password 'value' --permanent

However, I was to determine how I can execute a test login from AWS CloudShell commandline in order to verify if I set the password correctly.

I've been searching the internet for a while but I can't determine how to execute such a test login just to verify that the password is correctly setup.

What AWS CloudShell command would allow me to test login said User Account?